# python chat server /version command

Tags: python, server, command, chat, version

heres my code for my python chat server chatserver.py

its a chat server that when run should run multiple commands in the server but im having somve trouble with it

```
import socket
import sys
import threading
import Channel

class Server:
SERVER_CONFIG = {"MAX_CONNECTIONS": 15}

HELP_MESSAGE = """\n> The list of commands available are:

/help                   - Show the instructions
/join [channel_name]    - To create or switch to a channel.
/quit                   - Exits the program.
/list                   - Lists all available channels.\n\n""".encode('utf8')

def __init__(self, host=socket.gethostbyname('localhost'), port=50000, allowReuseAddress=True):
    self.address = (host, port)
    self.channels = {} # Channel Name -> Channel
    self.channels_client_map = {} # Client Name -> Channel Name

    try:
        self.serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    except socket.error as errorMessage:
        sys.stderr.write("Failed to initialize the server. Error - %s\n", str(errorMessage))
        raise

    if allowReuseAddress:
        self.serverSocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

    try:
        self.serverSocket.bind(self.address)
    except socket.error as errorMessage:
        sys.stderr.write('Failed to bind to ' + self.address + '. Error - %s\n', str(errorMessage))
        raise

def listen_thread(self, defaultGreeting="\n> Welcome to our chat app!!! What is your name?\n"):
    while True:
        print("Waiting for a client to establish a connection\n")
        clientSocket, clientAddress = self.serverSocket.accept()
        print("Connection established with IP address {0} and port {1}\n".format(clientAddress[0], clientAddress[1]))
        self.welcome_client(clientSocket)
        clientThread = threading.Thread(target=self.client_thread, args=(clientSocket,))
        clientThread.start()

def start_listening(self):
    self.serverSocket.listen(Server.SERVER_CONFIG["MAX_CONNECTIONS"])
    listenerThread = threading.Thread(target=self.listen_thread)
    listenerThread.start()
    listenerThread.join()

def welcome_client(self, clientSocket):
    clientSocket.sendall("\n> Welcome to our chat app!!! What is your name?\n".encode('utf8'))

def client_thread(self, clientSocket, size=4096):
    clientName = clientSocket.recv(size).decode('utf8')
    welcomeMessage = '> Welcome %s, type /help for a list of helpful commands.\n\n' % clientName
    clientSocket.send(welcomeMessage.encode('utf8'))

    while True:
        chatMessage = clientSocket.recv(size).decode('utf8').lower()

        if not chatMessage:
            break

        if '/quit' in chatMessage:
            self.quit(clientSocket, clientName)
            break
        elif '/list' in chatMessage:
            self.list_all_channels(clientSocket)
        elif '/help' in chatMessage:
            self.help(clientSocket)
        elif '/join' in chatMessage:
            self.join(clientSocket, chatMessage, clientName)
        else:
            self.send_message(clientSocket, chatMessage + '\n' , clientName)

    clientSocket.close()

def quit(self, clientSocket, clientName):
    clientSocket.sendall('/quit'.encode('utf8'))
    self.remove_client(clientName)

def list_all_channels(self, clientSocket):
    if len(self.channels) == 0:
        chatMessage = "\n> No rooms available. Create your own by typing /join [channel_name]\n"
        clientSocket.sendall(chatMessage.encode('utf8'))
    else:
        chatMessage = '\n\n> Current channels available are: \n'
        for channel in self.channels:
            chatMessage += "    \n" + channel + ": " + str(len(self.channels[channel].clients)) + " user(s)"
        chatMessage += "\n"
        clientSocket.sendall(chatMessage.encode('utf8'))

def help(self, clientSocket):
    clientSocket.sendall(Server.HELP_MESSAGE)

def join(self, clientSocket, chatMessage, clientName):
    isInSameRoom = False

    if len(chatMessage.split()) >= 2:
        channelName = chatMessage.split()[1]

        if clientName in self.channels_client_map: # Here we are switching to a new channel.
            if self.channels_client_map[clientName] == channelName:
                clientSocket.sendall(("\n> You are already in channel: " + channelName).encode('utf8'))
                isInSameRoom = True
            else: # switch to a new channel
                oldChannelName = self.channels_client_map[clientName]
                self.channels[oldChannelName].remove_client_from_channel(clientName) # remove them from the previous channel

        if not isInSameRoom:
            if not channelName in self.channels:
                newChannel = Channel.Channel(channelName)
                self.channels[channelName] = newChannel

            self.channels[channelName].clients[clientName] = clientSocket
            self.channels[channelName].welcome_client(clientName)
            self.channels_client_map[clientName] = channelName
    else:
        self.help(clientSocket)

def send_message(self, clientSocket, chatMessage, clientName):
    if clientName in self.channels_client_map:
        self.channels[self.channels_client_map[clientName]].broadcast_message(chatMessage, clientName + ": ")
    else:
        chatMessage = """\n> You are currently not in any channels:

Use /list to see a list of available channels.
Use /join [channel name] to join a channels.\n\n""".encode('utf8')

        clientSocket.sendall(chatMessage)

def remove_client(self, clientName):
    if clientName in self.channels_client_map:
        self.channels[self.channels_client_map[clientName]].remove_client_from_channel(clientName)
        del self.channels_client_map[clientName]
    print("Client: " + clientName + " has left\n")

def server_shutdown(self):
    print("Shutting down chat server.\n")
    self.serverSocket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    self.serverSocket.close()

def main():
chatServer = Server()

print("\nListening on port " + str(chatServer.address[1]))
print("Waiting for connections...\n")

chatServer.start_listening()
chatServer.server_shutdown()


if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

as you can see i have the commands /help /join/ /quit and /list
but im having trouble writing the /version command which does the following

```
VERSION
Syntax: VERSION [<server>]
Returns the version of <server>, or the current server if omitted
```

does anybody know how I can code this and help me write it

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it be very similar to your implementation of `/help`?

There is only one server so the version would be the same for all threads. So decide on a version number (that's another issue) then create a method that sends the version as a string to the client:

```
VERSION = '1.2.3'

def version(self, clientSocket):
    clientSocket.sendall(Server.VERSION)
```

You'd also need to add something to `client_thread()` to call `version()` when `/version` is received as a command.